# Error using SQL Server in electron with angular : __webpack_require__(...) is not a function

Tags: node.js, sql-server, angular, electron

I am trying to build Electron App with Angular framework using [this boilerplate code](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron)

I have to connect to SQL Server and I intend to use the [`mssql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) node js package.

I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: **webpack_require**(...) is not a function

when I try to use the package.

I have attempted the following ways of importing package:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

import * as sql from '../../../node_modules/mssql';

import * as sql from 'mssql';
```

But interestingly I don't get any errors when I import node js package `os` and a custom package `moment` normally as

```
import * as os from 'os';
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Comment: I have the same error when importing mssql in an electron app, any updates?